# Populate SQL Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following data from SQL


| SR.NO | ATTR-X | ATTR-Z |
---------------------------------------
| 1           | A            | a1          |
| 2           | B            | a2          |
| 3           | C            | a3          |
| 4           | A            | a4          |
---------------------------------------
I want this to

| SR | A | B | C | ATTR-Z |
----------------------------------
| 1    | A |  -  | -  |      a1      |
| 2    |  -  | B | -  |      a2      |
| 3    |  -  | -  | C |      a3      |
| 4    | A |  -  | -  |      a4      |
----------------------------------

Can we do it in SQL queries itself?

Comment: Please start learning HTML, PHP and MYSQL from the beginning

Comment: Please state your DBMS, in MS SQL I already did a lot of nasty XML manipulation but it's simplier in a "XML friendly" like C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement to determine what is needed in each column.

```
SELECT SR_NO, CASE WHEN [Attribute -X] = 'A' THEN A ELSE NULL END AS 'A',
              CASE WHEN [Attribute -X] = 'B' THEN B ELSE NULL END AS 'B',
              CASE WHEN [Attribute -X] = 'C' THEN C ELSE NULL END AS 'C',
      [Attribute -Z] AS 'ATTR-Z'
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for solution, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify a bit further? Do you have that Data in SQL and want it populated in your HTML form?

Or

Did you mean you just want the exact same data to show up in an SQL Query

If just a simple query can do this

```
    select 1 as SR_NO, 'A' as A,'-' as B , '-' as C, 'a1' as [ATTR-Z]
    union all
    select 2 as SR_NO, '-' as A,'B' as B , '-' as C, 'a2' as [ATTR-Z]
    union all
    select 3 as SR_NO, 'A' as A,'-' as B , '-' as C, 'a3' as [ATTR-Z]
    union all
    select 4 as SR_NO, '-' as A,'-' as B , 'C' as C, 'a4' as [ATTR-Z]
```

However this isn't really useful for anything other than displaying the table you just showed - if you want it to follow a certain pattern/cases then you'd need to let us know more about what you'd want.